# Why does my daemon-like Python script run multiple times?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I start a Python script from a bash script in `/etc/init.d` using `sudo /etc/init.d/fanservice.sh start` (or stop)

It starts and stops as expected, and starts on boot. The Python script works well.

However, in `top` or `htop` I see that the script is running multiple times.

What might be causing this, and how do I stop it?
Other than looking around for other triggers (I've checked there are no old references to the script in crontab) I'm not sure where else to look.

This is `/etc/init.d/fanservice.sh`

I run the Python script as root to allow access to GPIO.

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myservice
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Put a short description of the service here
# Description:       Put a long description of the service here
### END INIT INFO

# Change the next 3 lines to suit where you install your script and what you want to call it
DIR=/home/pi
DAEMON=$DIR/fanservice.py
DAEMON_NAME=fanservice

# Add any command line options for your daemon here
DAEMON_OPTS=""

# This next line determines what user the script runs as.
# Root generally not recommended but necessary if you are using the Raspberry Pi GPIO from Python.
DAEMON_USER=root

# The process ID of the script when it runs is stored here:
PIDFILE=/var/run/$DAEMON_NAME.pid

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start () {
    log_daemon_msg "Starting system $DAEMON_NAME daemon"
    start-stop-daemon --start --background --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --user $DAEMON_USER --chuid $DAEMON_USER --startas $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
    log_end_msg $?
}
do_stop () {
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping system $DAEMON_NAME daemon"
    start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile $PIDFILE --retry 10
    log_end_msg $?
}

case "$1" in

    start|stop)
        do_${1}
        ;;

    restart|reload|force-reload)
        do_stop
        do_start
        ;;

    status)
        status_of_proc "$DAEMON_NAME" "$DAEMON" && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;

    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/$DAEMON_NAME {start|stop|restart|status}"
        exit 1
        ;;

esac
exit 0
```

The Python script uses wiringPi, GPIO, tach and Paho.mqtt to read a temperature, set a fan speed, read the speed from the tach then send an MQTT message to a broker. All that is contained in a while True: loop with a time.sleep(58) at the end, so what I'm expecting is for the 'service' to start and loop every 58 seconds.

It does this, but every minute or so a new instance appears in top.

If I examine `/var/run/fanservice.pid` where the script PID is stored, I see it has the PID of the first instance.

For example, after 15 or 20 minutes htop will show the script running with a PID that matches that stored in PID file, and that process will have a time of XX minutes and seconds since boot. Then there'll be XX duplicate processes with their own PIDs, all with a time of 00:00.00, and the number of them will correspond (I think) with the number of minutes since boot.

Any tips very welcome. The init.d script is one I found on the internet, can't remember where - but I think I've probably broken that somehow! That said, I moved to running these tasks in a timer loop rather than from cron because the Python script wasn't exiting after being called by cron. I also have other scripts running in this way that need a faster loop than the minimum 1 minute from cron, so I'd like to learn how to make this work properly.

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using SysV-style init scripts? Even if you're sticking to tiny, minimal systems, there are still better ways to do it -- if you don't have or want to run systemd, take a look at [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) or its slightly-more-modern cousin [s6](https://skarnet.org/software/s6/). And if the distro you're using *does* ship systemd, then... well, you already have it and are paying the costs; might as well use it for what it does well.

Comment: (cron is likewise very much the Wrong Thing; a real process supervision system can automatically trigger a restart or other desired/configured event whenever it gets a SIGCHILD from your process exiting, so it responds *immediately* with zero polling overhead; no `sleep` loops anywhere).

Comment: Thanks, I will try systemd instead and update!

Comment: I successfully changed to systemd, thanks for the advice. The same issue exists though - after a while, there are multiple copies of the Python script running. Could it be that systemd detects that my script is not responding and starts an new copy?

Comment: That's an interesting result. Does the main PID exit and leave child processes running? What's the service type you're specifying?

Comment: ...though as `KillMode=control-group` is default, I almost wonder if the SIGTERM is being ignored by the other processes -- that might be a case where we need to use `KillMode=mixed` (for a nasty solution), or trace what's going on (how those processes are forked off, whether they're managing to exit the control group, etc) with a tool like [sysdig](https://sysdig.org/) to allow for a more targeted fix.

Comment: systemd *can* be configured to restart programs that are nonresponsive, but you need to go out of your way to set that it up -- it requires `Type=notify`, and that the program be set up to "pet" the watchdog (inform systemd that it's still operating correctly) via a SD_NOTIFY socket, the location of which is passed in an environment variable. And it does try to actually *restart* such programs, shutting down the old instances, when so configured. (There was once a bug that could cause the symptom you're describing, but it's in what are now very, very old releases).

Comment: The main PID seems to remain.

I believe this to be the case because if I run htop and sort by command, after a while there are many (ie, pages) of identical processes all with unique PIDs, and all with quite short time+ values - from zero to 0:00.11 or 0:00.12, but one process alone has a time of, for example, 9:59.50.

I think that single process is the first instance of the script, and that somehow loads of others are starting, not using any (or very little) CPU time but not closing!

Comment: This is the service script:

`[Unit]
Description=Fan Service
After=multi-user.target
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/fanservice.py
StandardInput=tty-force

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target`

Comment: If the main PID stays open, it's probably not systemd starting the children; rather, they're more likely being forked off by the main process itself.  Don't look at how many PIDs there are, look at the tree with the parent/child relationships.

Comment: Also, note that its often *completely correct* for one instance of a program to have lots of process-table entries (be they threads, [`multiprocessing` forked-off subprocesses](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), or something else). Without knowing anything about the program itself, we're not in a place to say what does or doesn't constitute behaving-as-written.

Comment: That said, one thing you *can* do is ask systemd to show you the status for your service, which will show you the main PID's identity and process-tree as it understands them; see `systemctl status yourservice`.